# JQM Buttons won't enhance with Backbone.js, Underscore.js, and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app that is using Backbone.js to manage models, views, and collections, Underscore.js to handle view templates, and jQuery Mobile and Bootstrap for the user interface.  Many of my view templates have buttons in them, but when the view is rendered the buttons will not enhance.  Everything in the view is enhanced but the buttons.

See the screenshot showing a portion of a form in one of my views:

[image: Form View]

As you can see, the `select` elements enhance as expected as do `textarea` elements.  I have `text input`, `checkbox`, `radio button`, `date input`, and `number input` elements in my form as well that also enhance.  After the view is rendered using it's `render` function I call `view.$el.trigger('create')`, which enhances everything within the view to use JQM styles, but not the buttons.

I've tried calling `.button()`, `.trigger('create')`, and `.buttonMarkup()` on the button itself, but it has no effect.

I am using JQM v1.3.2, jQuery v1.10.2, Underscore.js v1.5.2, Backbone.js v1.1.0, and Bootstrap v3.1.1.

Any ideas how I can make the buttons enhance to use JQM styles?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a simple jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4BzW/

**UPDATE 2:**

I have created another jsFiddle that does not use views.  It is simply HTML with External Resources loaded for jQuery, jQuery Mobile, Underscore.js, Backbone.js, and Bootstrap.  Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/g77bA/

I originally had Bootstrap as the last external resource and the button would not enhance.  Then, when I removed jQuery Mobile and re-added it as the last external resource, the button would enhance.  It looks like it could be as simple as Bootstrap overriding jQuery Mobile as both have a `button()` function.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Should I be concerned about anything else breaking in my app by overriding Bootstrap with jQuery Mobile?

Comment: do you have data-role="button" on the button markup?

Comment: @ezanker - I do have `data-role="button"` on the markup, but it still doesn't work.  I've also tried using `button`, `a`, and `input type="button"`.

Comment: is it possible to setup a simple fiddle? it should be enhanced since it's within the container where you call `create`.

Comment: @Omar - I've added a jsFiddle link to the original post.